# How can I put a ternary operator in the GuiControl command in AHK?

Tags: if-statement, user-interface, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a form screen that resets all of the fields when
the "Add" or "Edit" buttons are clicked. Whenever the function is run, I want to get the row value of the selected row. When I click the "Add" button, I want to reset all of the fields. When I click "Edit", I want the currently selected row as `RowValue`. The first step, though, is making this work. Here is my code:

`MainScript.ahk`

```
SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir%
SetNumLockState, AlwaysOn
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff

; Variables
OrangeMode := False
IniRead GuideShowing, Preferences.ini, Toggles, ShowGuide, True
IniRead, EmuNumpad, Preferences.ini, Toggles, EmulatedNumericalPad, False

KeybindArray := [[]]
KeybindArray[1][1] := 1
KeybindArray[1][2] := "G"
KeybindArray[1][3] := 4
KeybindArray[1][4] := 1
KeybindArray[1][5] := 4
KeybindArray[1][6] := 4
KeybindArray[1][7] := 4
KeybindArray[1][8] := 3
KeybindArray[1][9] := 2
KeybindArray[1][10] := 1
KeybindArray[1][11] := ""
KeybindArray[1][12] := ""
KeybindArray[1][13] := "https://verylong.websitename.com"

; Tags
#Persistent
#Include GuiScript.ahk

; Functions
SetGui(Name, RowValue=0) {
    If (Name = "Keybind") {
        Keybind_Key_Main := % (RowValue=0 ? 0 : KeybindArray[RowValue][1])
        Keybind_Key_Win := % (RowValue=0 ? 1 : KeybindArray[RowValue][2])
        Keybind_Key_CapsLock := % (RowValue=0 ? 0 : KeybindArray[RowValue][3])
        Keybind_Key_Shift := % (RowValue=0 ? 1 : KeybindArray[RowValue][4])
        Keybind_Key_Alt := % (RowValue=0 ? 1 : KeybindArray[RowValue][5])
        Keybind_Key_Ctrl := % (RowValue=0 ? 1 : KeybindArray[RowValue][6])
        Keybind_Option_Type := % (RowValue=0 ? 1 : KeybindArray[RowValue][7])
        Keybind_Option_Mode := % (RowValue=0 ? 1 : KeybindArray[RowValue][8])
        Keybind_Option_GoBlue := % (RowValue=0 ? 0 : KeybindArray[RowValue][9])
        Keybind_Option_Remap := % (RowValue=0 ? 1 : KeybindArray[RowValue][10])
        Keybind_Option_Preset := % (RowValue=0 ? 1 : KeybindArray[RowValue][11])
        Keybind_Option_Website := % (RowValue=0 ? "https://" : KeybindArray[RowValue][12])
        
        GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Main, % Keybind_Key_Main
        GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Win, % Keybind_Key_Win
        GuiControl,, Keybind_Key_CapsLock, % Keybind_Key_CapsLock
        GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Shift, % Keybind_Key_Shift
        GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Alt, % Keybind_Key_Alt
        GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Ctrl, % Keybind_Key_Ctrl
        GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Option_Type, % Keybind_Option_Type
        GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Option_Mode, % Keybind_Option_Mode
        GuiControl,, Keybind_Option_GoBlue, % Keybind_Option_GoBlue
        GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Option_Remap, % Keybind_Option_Remap
        GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Option_Preset, % Keybind_Option_Preset
        GuiControl,, Keybind_Option_Website, % Keybind_Option_Website
    } Else If (Name = Text) {
; Not coded yet
    }
}
Build_Restart() {
    MsgBox The Build_Restart function has been run ; WIP
}

; Subroutines (G-Labels)
BuildRestart:
    Build_Restart()
    Return
KeybindMenu_Add:
    SetGui("Keybind", 0) ; Clear all form boxes
    Gui Keybind:Show, Center w400 h300, Add Keybind ; Open the Keybind Edit GUI with a new keybind
    Return
KeybindMenu_Edit:
    SetGui("Keybind", 0) ; Clear all form boxes
    Gui Keybind:Show, Center w400 h300, Edit Keybind ; Open the Keybind Edit GUI with the currently selected row
    Return
KeybindMenu_Del:
    Return
KeybindEdit_Save:
    Gui Keybind:Hide ; Hide the Keybind Edit GUI
    MsgBox, 52, Build and Restart, New changes will not take effect until they are applied.`nWould you like to Build and Restart?
    IfMsgBox Yes
        Build_Restart()
        Return
    Return
KeybindEdit_Cancel:
    Gui Keybind:Hide ; Hide the Keybind Edit GUI
    Return
Keybind_Option_Type-Changed:
    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Remap
    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Preset
    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Website
    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_App
    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Custom

    GuiControlGet, Keybind_Option_Type,, Keybind_Option_Type
    If (Keybind_Option_Type = 1) {
        GuiControl, Show, Keybind_Option_Remap
    } Else If (Keybind_Option_Type = 2) {
        GuiControl, Show, Keybind_Option_Preset
    } Else If (Keybind_Option_Type = 3) {
        GuiControl, Show, Keybind_Option_Website
    } Else If (Keybind_Option_Type = 4) {
        GuiControl, Show, Keybind_Option_App
    } Else If (Keybind_Option_Type = 5) {
        GuiControl, Show, Keybind_Option_Custom
    }
    Return
Keybind_Option_Mode-Changed:
    GuiControlGet, Keybind_Option_Mode,, Keybind_Option_Mode
    If (Keybind_Option_Mode = 1) OR (Keybind_Option_Mode = 2) {
        GuiControl, Enable, Keybind_Option_GoBlue
    } else {
        GuiControl,, Keybind_Option_GoBlue, 0
        GuiControl, Disable, Keybind_Option_GoBlue
    }
    Return
KeybindListAction:  
    If (A_GuiEvent == "I") AND ( InStr(ErrorLevel,"S",true) ) {
        KeybindCurrentSelection := %A_GuiEvent%

        GuiControl, Enable, KeybindMenu_Edit
        GuiControl, Enable, KeybindMenu_Del
    } Else If (A_GuiEvent == "I") AND ( InStr(ErrorLevel,"S",false)) {
        GuiControl, Disable, KeybindMenu_Edit
        GuiControl, Disable, KeybindMenu_Del
    }
    Return

; --KEYBINDS--
>^LButton::MButton ; RCtrl + LeftClick = MiddleClick
F9::OrangeMode:=!OrangeMode ; Toggle the orange mode
; When Orange Mode is active
#If OrangeMode
    /::
        GuideShowing:=!GuideShowing ; Toggle visibility of the orange mode guide
        IniWrite, %GuideShowing%, Preferences.ini, Toggles, ShowGuide ; Update the preferences file
        Return
    N::
        Run C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe ; Open Notepad
        OrangeMode:=false ; Close Orange Mode
        Return
    Q::
        EmuNumpad:=!EmuNumpad ; Toggle the emulated numerical pad
        IniWrite, %EmuNumpad%, Preferences.ini, Toggles, EmulatedNumericalPad ; Update the preferences file
        Return
#If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P") AND OrangeMode ; When CapsLock is pressed during Orange Mode
    A::Gui Settings:Show, Center w500 h400 ; Open the Settings GUI
    M::Run MainScript.ahk ; Restart the program
; When the Numerical Pad is being emulated
#If EmuNumpad ; When the numerical pad is emulated, use numerical keys when holding {Alt}
    !1::!Numpad1
    !2::!Numpad2
    !3::!Numpad3
    !4::!Numpad4
    !5::!Numpad5
    !6::!Numpad6
    !7::!Numpad7
    !8::!Numpad8
    !9::!Numpad9
    !0::!Numpad0
```

`GuiScript.ahk`

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines -1

Gui Keybind:New, -MinimizeBox -MaximizeBox, Add/Edit Keybind ; Create Keybind Edit GUI
    Gui Keybind:Default
    Gui Font, s10, Lexend
    Gui Margin, 15, 15

    Gui Add, Text, x15 y15 w220 h40, Type a single character - "A"`nType a key's name - "Backspace"
    Gui Add, ComboBox, x230 y24 w140 h200 vKeybind_Key_Main, LButton|RButton|MButton|XButton1|XButton2|WheelDown|WheelUp|WheelLeft|WheelRight|Space|Tab|Enter|Escape|Backspace|Delete|Home|End|PgUp|PgDn|Up|Down|Left|Right|PrintScreen|Numpad0|Numpad1|Numpad2|Numpad3|Numpad4|Numpad5|Numpad6|Numpad7|Numpad8|Numpad9|NumpadDot|NumpadDiv|NumpadMult|NumpadAdd|NumpadSub|NumpadEnter|F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8|F9|F10|F11|F12|F13|F14|F15|F16|F17|F18|F19|F20|F21|F22|F23|F24
    Gui Add, DropDownList, x15 y70 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Key_Win, No Win||Left Win|Right Win|Both Win|Either Win
    Gui Add, CheckBox, x140 y73 w120 vKeybind_Key_CapsLock, CapsLock
    Gui Add, DropDownList, x265 y70 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Key_Shift, No Shift||Left Shift|Right Shift|Both Shift|Either Shift
    Gui Add, DropDownList, x15 y105 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Key_Alt, No Alt||Left Alt|Right Alt|Both Alt|Either Alt
    Gui Add, DropDownList, x140 y105 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Key_Ctrl, No Ctrl||Left Ctrl|Right Ctrl|Both Ctrl|Either Ctrl

    Gui Add, DropDownList, x15 y150 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Option_Type gKeybind_Option_Type-Changed, Remap||Preset|Website|App|Custom
    Gui Add, DropDownList, x140 y150 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Option_Mode gKeybind_Option_Mode-Changed, Either Mode||Orange Mode|Blue Mode
    Gui Add, CheckBox, x265 y153 w120 vKeybind_Option_GoBlue, Go to Blue

    Gui Add, ComboBox, x15 y195 w180 h200 vKeybind_Option_Remap, Disable Keybind||LButton|RButton|MButton|XButton1|XButton2|WheelDown|WheelUp|WheelLeft|WheelRight|Space|Tab|Enter|Escape|Backspace|Delete|Home|End|PgUp|PgDn|Up|Down|Left|Right|PrintScreen|Numpad0|Numpad1|Numpad2|Numpad3|Numpad4|Numpad5|Numpad6|Numpad7|Numpad8|Numpad9|NumpadDot|NumpadDiv|NumpadMult|NumpadAdd|NumpadSub|NumpadEnter|F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8|F9|F10|F11|F12|F13|F14|F15|F16|F17|F18|F19|F20|F21|F22|F23|F24
    Gui Add, DropDownList, x15 y195 w180 AltSubmit vKeybind_Option_Preset, Restart Program||Toggle Emulated Numpad|Send Notification
    Gui Add, Edit, x15 y195 w180 r2 -WantReturn Wrap vKeybind_Option_Website, https://

    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Remap
    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Preset
    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Website
    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_App ; Yet to be added
    GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Custom ; Yet to be added

    Gui Add, Button, x75 y260 w120 h30 gKeybindEdit_Save, &Save Keybind
    Gui Add, Button, x205 y260 w120 h30 gKeybindEdit_Cancel, &Cancel

    ;Gui Show, Center w400 h300
Gui Settings:New, -MinimizeBox -MaximizeBox, Orange Mode Settings
    Gui Settings:Default
    Gui Font, s10, Lexend
    Gui Margin, 15, 15

    Gui Add, Tab3, -Wrap x0 y5 w500 h395, General|AutoClicker|Keybinds|Text Shortcuts

    Gui Tab, 1, 1
        Gui Add, Button, -Wrap x190 y50 w120 gBuildRestart, Build and &Restart
    ;
    Gui Tab, 2, 1
    ;
    Gui Tab, 3, 1
        Gui Add, Button, -Wrap x55 y40 w120 h30 gKeybindMenu_Add, &Add Keybind
        Gui Add, Button, -Wrap Disabled x185 y40 w120 h30 gKeybindMenu_Edit vKeybindMenu_Edit, &Edit Keybind
        Gui Add, Button, -Wrap Disabled x315 y40 w120 h30 gKeybindMenu_Del vKeybindMenu_Del, &Delete Keybind

        Gui Add, ListView, -LV0x10 -Multi Checked x20 y80 w460 h300 AltSubmit gKeybindListAction,  |Keybind|Type|Action|Mode
        LV_ModifyCol(1, 25)
        LV_ModifyCol(2, 250)
        LV_ModifyCol(3, 100)
        LV_ModifyCol(4, 300)
        LV_ModifyCol(5, 125)
    ;
    LV_Add(Check, 1,"CapsLock+LCtrl+RCtrl+LShift+RShift+LAlt+RAlt+LWin+RWin+G", "Website", "https://verylong.websitename.com", "Orange; Go Blue") ; For testing purposes

    ;Gui Show, Center w500 h400
Return
```

However, when I open the menu, change something, then exit and click one of the two buttons, nothing happens - the input fields do not clear/reset.

How can I fix this problem?

*Note: If you have an idea for a better way of doing this, let me know - I'm open to suggestions.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you posted, two things can be observed:

1. You are passing a blank variable to the function (which, from what
   can be understood, should be a string).
2. To use the ternary operator in GuiControl, you need to enable
   expression mode in the field( % sign ).

   ```
   Gui Add, ComboBox, x230 y24 w140 h200 vKeybind_Key_Main, LButton|RButton|MButton|XButton1|XButton2|WheelDown|WheelUp|WheelLeft|WheelRight|Space|Tab|Enter|Escape|Backspace|Delete|Home|End|PgUp|PgDn|Up|Down|Left|Right|PrintScreen|Numpad0|Numpad1|Numpad2|Numpad3|Numpad4|Numpad5|Numpad6|Numpad7|Numpad8|Numpad9|NumpadDot|NumpadDiv|NumpadMult|NumpadAdd|NumpadSub|NumpadEnter|F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8|F9|F10|F11|F12|F13|F14|F15|F16|F17|F18|F19|F20|F21|F22|F23|F24
   Gui Add, DropDownList, x15 y70 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Key_Win, No Win||Left Win|Right Win|Both Win|Either Win
   Gui Add, CheckBox, x140 y73 w120 vKeybind_Key_CapsLock, CapsLock
   Gui Add, DropDownList, x265 y70 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Key_Shift, No Shift||Left Shift|Right Shift|Both Shift|Either Shift
   Gui Add, DropDownList, x15 y105 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Key_Alt, No Alt||Left Alt|Right Alt|Both Alt|Either Alt
   Gui Add, DropDownList, x140 y105 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Key_Ctrl, No Ctrl||Left Ctrl|Right Ctrl|Both Ctrl|Either Ctrl

   Gui Add, DropDownList, x15 y150 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Option_Type gKeybind_Option_Type-Changed, Remap||Preset|Website|App|Custom
   Gui Add, DropDownList, x140 y150 w120 AltSubmit vKeybind_Option_Mode gKeybind_Option_Mode-Changed, Either Mode||Orange Mode|Blue Mode
   Gui Add, CheckBox, x265 y153 w120 vKeybind_Option_GoBlue, Go to Blue

   Gui Add, ComboBox, x15 y195 w180 h200 vKeybind_Option_Remap, Disable Keybind||LButton|RButton|MButton|XButton1|XButton2|WheelDown|WheelUp|WheelLeft|WheelRight|Space|Tab|Enter|Escape|Backspace|Delete|Home|End|PgUp|PgDn|Up|Down|Left|Right|PrintScreen|Numpad0|Numpad1|Numpad2|Numpad3|Numpad4|Numpad5|Numpad6|Numpad7|Numpad8|Numpad9|NumpadDot|NumpadDiv|NumpadMult|NumpadAdd|NumpadSub|NumpadEnter|F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8|F9|F10|F11|F12|F13|F14|F15|F16|F17|F18|F19|F20|F21|F22|F23|F24
   Gui Add, DropDownList, x15 y195 w180 AltSubmit vKeybind_Option_Preset, Restart Program||Toggle Emulated Numpad|Send Notification
   Gui Add, Edit, x15 y195 w180 r2 -WantReturn Wrap vKeybind_Option_Website, https://

   GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Remap
   GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Preset
   GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Website
   GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_App
   GuiControl, Hide, Keybind_Option_Custom
   ; The code creating the buttons
   Gui Add, Button, -Wrap x55 y40 w120 h30 gKeybindMenu_Add, &Add Keybind
   Gui Add, Button, -Wrap Disabled x185 y40 w120 h30 gKeybindMenu_Edit vKeybindMenu_Edit, &Edit Keybind
   Gui, Show
   Return
   ; The function with the code
   SetGui(Name, RowValue=0) {

       if (Name = "Keybind") {
           GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Main,% (RowValue=0 ? 0 : Keybind_Key_Main)
           GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Win,% (RowValue=0 ? 1 : Keybind_Key_Win)
           GuiControl,, Keybind_Key_CapsLock,% (RowValue=0 ? 0 : Keybind_Key_CapsLock)
           GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Shift,% (RowValue=0 ? 1 : Keybind_Key_Shift)
           GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Alt,% (RowValue=0 ? 1 : Keybind_Key_Alt)
           GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Key_Ctrl,% (RowValue=0 ? 1 : Keybind_Key_Ctrl)
           GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Option_Type,% (RowValue=0 ? 1 : Keybind_Option_Type)
           GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Option_Mode,% (RowValue=0 ? 1 : Keybind_Option_Mode)
           GuiControl,, Keybind_Option_GoBlue,% (RowValue=0 ? 0 : Keybind_Option_GoBlue)
           GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Option_Remap,% (RowValue=0 ? 1 : Keybind_Option_Remap)
           GuiControl, Choose, Keybind_Option_Preset,% (RowValue=0 ? 1 : Keybind_Option_Preset)
           GuiControl,, Keybind_Option_Website,% (RowValue=0 ? "https://" : Keybind_Option_Website)
       }
   }

   ; The two button subs running that function
   KeybindMenu_Add:
       SetGui("Keybind", 0) ; Clear all form boxes
       ; MsgBox % "Clicked Add"
       Gui Keybind:Show, Center w400 h300, Add Keybind ; Open the Keybind Edit GUI with a new keybind
   Return

   KeybindMenu_Edit:
       SetGui("Keybind", 0) ; Clear all form boxes
           Gui Keybind:Show, Center w400 h300, Edit Keybind ; Open the Keybind Edit GUI with the currently selected row
   Return

   Keybind_Option_Mode-Changed:    ; just to avoid errors
   Keybind_Option_Type-Changed:    ; just to avoid errors
           Return
   ```

[image: Running the code]

Comment: I applied all of your code, but it still doesn't work. All of the DDLs, CheckBoxes, etc. keep the value they had before I ran the function.

Comment: I'll update and post the entire code that i've used to simulate. It's working pretty fine here.

Comment: About getting the values, you will need to use Gui, Submit, NoHide and use the values in the vars, but, as your posted code is incomplete, it is difficult to assist you in where to update the code and why.

Comment: Weird - my code doesn't update the values at all. Could it have something to do with my Guis being in a different script than all the other code?

Comment: Good news! I tested the code you used, and it worked perfectly well. Should I send you more code from my scripts, so you can try to find a reason?

Comment: If you want to edit your first post and provide the complete code, I can check it for you and try to identify the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I modified the question to include all relevant code.

Comment: I just updated the code some more - I switched to setting the values of all the variables because I will need to do more with them in the function.

Comment: I see what's going on, you are using named GUIs. Before i try something, just add `Gui, Keybind:Default` inside your `SetGui()` function, right under the `If (Name = "Keybind") {` line and try, this probably will work. While using named GUIs, it is a good practice to always specify in the code which of the GUIs the commands should be applied to.

Comment: Like magic, it works! Thank you so much!